# Is it possible to update views columns automatically (Mysql)?

Tags: mysql, view

I have the following scenario:

There is one database (main) that holds common information such as 'modules', 'menu', etc and one database for each project containing a view for each of those tables in main database. For example:

**main**

- modules (id, description)
- menu (id, label, href, ...)
- ...

**project1**

- modules_view
- menu_view

Those views where created as simple as:

```
CREATE VIEW menu_view AS SELECT * FROM main.menu
```

Now, I have to create an 'order' column for the menu but the view columns aren't being updated.

```
ALTER TABLE `menu` ADD `menu_order` INT NOT NULL AFTER `href`;
```

Is it possible to maintain the views columns updated without having to do it mannualy each time I have to create a new column in the main table?

---

OBS: there are 10+ projects... So it will become harder to maintain as this number grows

Comment: What is an `order` column?  How are you creating it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated =)

Comment: What you mean is to **ALTER** the views automatically whenever any of the base tables is **ALTERE**d?

Comment: @FDavidov yes, thats it

Comment: Well, I cannot assert it with 100% certainty, but my guess would be a clear and round **NO** unless, somehow, this can be done through triggers on the main tables that would **ALTER** the corresponding views (also doubtful). Last, even if this is doable, I would strongly recommend you take a careful consideration. In other words, DON'T DO IT (!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the view using `*`:

```
CREATE VIEW menu_view AS
    SELECT * FROM main.menu;
```

Alas, the `*` is interpreted when the view is *created*, not when the view is *run*.  You can actually see in the metadata that the columns are defined.

The only way to do what you want is to recompile/alter the views for the new columns.

This is explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html):

> The view definition is “frozen” at creation time and is not affected
>   by subsequent changes to the definitions of the underlying tables. For
>   example, if a view is defined as `SELECT *` on a table, new columns
>   added to the table later do not become part of the view, and columns
>   dropped from the table will result in an error when selecting from the
>   view.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to find another way

Answer (score 1):

You can have one text/sql file with the definition of all your views and run it everytime you update your tables. So, you don't need to update every view.

Something like that:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS menu_view;
CREATE VIEW menu_view AS
    SELECT * FROM main.menu;

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS table2_view;
CREATE VIEW table2_view AS
    SELECT * FROM main.table2;
```

Comment: Interesting solution/concept. We've implemented with database versioning/migrations at the time but this could be an option

Comment: It's the solution that I'm using on every project. It's incredible that on 2022 MySQL don't have any way to do this!